# Java progrWrite a program in Java in DD array to convert all the elements into next prime numbers and display the changed array

Tags: iphone

Write a program in Java in DD array to convert all the elements into next prime numbers and display the changed array

Comment: what's the problem? what have you tried?

Comment: Really ?! This is not a "get my program done for free website".